# onItemLongClickListener is working weird

Tags: android

My code is below
my problem is when activity is first open long click on listview is not working.And then again i hold the item in listview it will work.why this happening anyone has any idea.
Thanks in Advance

```
editListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new       AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            editListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            editListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long l, boolean b) {
                    actionMode.setTitle(editListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected");

                    // Toggle the state of item after every click on it
                    mAdapterEdit.toggleSelection(position);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_group_edit, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete_action) {

                        SparseBooleanArray selected = mAdapterEdit.getSelectedIds();
                        short size = (short) selected.size();
                        for (byte I = 0; I < size; I++) {
                            if (selected.valueAt(I)) {
                                GroupContactDAO selectedItem = mAdapterEdit
                                        .getItem(selected.keyAt(I));
                                mAdapterEdit.remove(selectedItem);
                            }
                        }
                        actionMode.finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `setChoiceMode()` and `setMultiChoiceModeListener()` inside your `OnItemLongClickListener`, which means these methods will not get called until you perform a long click on a list item.

Put `editListView.setChoiceMode()` and `editListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener()` outside of your `OnItemLongClickListener`:

```
editListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
editListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    // ...
}

editListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Work like charm.